# SyntaxError: Number.toString() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why do I get an error on this, in Javascript:

```
10000000.toString();
```

You can see an example in here:
http://jsbin.com/kagijayecu/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the JS parser is expecting more digits after the "." rather than a method name, e.g. `1000000.0`, and in fact `1000000.0.toString()` will work as expected.

Comment: `1000000..toString()` works too.

Answer (score 4):

wrap it inside `()` like this `(10000000).toString()`

When JS parse meets dot after digit it expects floating-point literal, e.g. `1000000.0`